# Traffic Generator with Checkpoint

Tags: gem5

Is there any way to run Traffic Generator with Checkpoints. Basically my problem is I am running a trace through my memory model and it is faulting at around 110M instructions. Everytime I want to debug I have to wait till 110M instructions. Is it possible for me to save a checkpoint at lets say 100M and then resume from there for quick debugging?

Any guidance will be of great help!

Comment: In `fs.py`, I think you can achieve that with: `--take-checkpoints`. I would look at how it's implemented and try something similar, related: https://gem5-users.gem5.narkive.com/F0rkgfb8/question-on-creating-restoring-checkpoint-for-a-specific-number-of-instructions Mailing list thread for this post: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16520.html

Comment: is it not possible to do it in se.py?

Comment: `gem5.opt se.py --help` says that it also has the `--take-checkpoints` option, so I guess it will work there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to try this. Also in my memory model, lets say i've added a FIFO. Now while taking a checkpoint, how do I save the state of the FIFO? Basically what needs to be done so that the state of the FIFO is saved. 
PS: I've recently started using gem5 (newbie)

Comment: Hi, 
I tried the below command
/build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py --at-instruction --take-checkpoints=1000 --trace-file=sample_trace.csv.trc.gz
but there are no checkpoints being created.

Comment: newbie: don't worry about it, we are all learning here. FIFO: would this be different than any other checkpoint implementation for other devices? If not, I'd study them, otherwise, if you don't manage try explaining how your attempted failed on a new thread. I haven't touched checkpoint code yet, but I suspect it is simple. no checkpoints: I'm not sure what is going on, I've never used it myself. I would try the following: see if the checkpoints are generated in fs.py as well as a sanity check. Then have a look at the source / GDB step debug it, it should be simple code I suspect.

Comment: Are you using a custom made FIFO, or the one provided in Gem5? (Fifo, in src/base/circlebuf.hh). I haven't tested checkpointing them, but their arrayParamIn and Out functions are there, writing in and out the internal storage, so you likely just need to make it inherit from Serializable and implement the serialize() and unserialize() functions to save the variables that you need on your checkpoints (theoretically speaking; I have never done that).